# IOS app missing purpose string in info.plist while it is added

Tags: ios, app-store, info.plist

my ios app was rejected 3x now because missing purpose string from info.plist. Apple says I have to add purpose string for location usage. Funny thing is, I have added, it is in the info.plist but for some reason neither the phone, neither Apple find it. What do I do wrong?!

Here is part of my info.plist (sensitive info deleted out):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>----</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>13.0</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>-----</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <array>
        <string>App would like to use location to track the exact location of the vehicle in real time. Also notify our warehouses when the driver is arriving.</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <array>
        <string>App would like to use location to track the exact location of the vehicle in real time. Also notify our warehouses when the driver is arriving.</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <array>
        <string>App would like to use location to track the exact location of the vehicle in real time. Also notify our warehouses when the driver is arriving</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: Use string instead of array for location description key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your Info.plist file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>----</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>13.0</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>-----</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>App would like to use location to track the exact location of the vehicle in real time. Also notify our warehouses when the driver is arriving.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>App would like to use location to track the exact location of the vehicle in real time. Also notify our warehouses when the driver is arriving.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>App would like to use location to track the exact location of the vehicle in real time. Also notify our warehouses when the driver is arriving</string>
```

You need to add an only string for location permission And you have added it inside the array.

Hope It will work for you.

Comment: it fixed it! it should not be in array. Thank you so much!